# How to extend TextButton?

Tags: flutter

I want to extend `TextButton`, the codes likes below:

```
class KMTextButton extends TextButton {
  const KMTextButton({
    Key? key,
    required VoidCallback? onPressed,
    VoidCallback? onLongPress,
    ButtonStyle? style,
    FocusNode? focusNode,
    bool autofocus = false,
    Clip clipBehavior = Clip.none,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(
    key: key,
    onPressed: (){
      print('onPressedFuncInvoked');
      if (onPressed != null) {
        onPressed();
      }
    },
    onLongPress: onLongPress,
    style: style,
    focusNode: focusNode,
    autofocus: autofocus,
    clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
    child: child,
  );

}
```

Then I will get an error `invalid constant value`, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

remove `const` keyword from your code.
like this

```
class KMTextButton extends TextButton {
   KMTextButton({
    Key? key,
    required VoidCallback? onPressed,
    VoidCallback? onLongPress,
    ButtonStyle? style,
    FocusNode? focusNode,
    bool autofocus = false,
    Clip clipBehavior = Clip.none,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(
    key: key,
    onPressed: (){
      print('onPressedFuncInvoked');
      if (onPressed != null) {
        onPressed();
      }
    },
    onLongPress: onLongPress,
    style: style,
    focusNode: focusNode,
    autofocus: autofocus,
    clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
    child: child,
  );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a `non-const` `super` because `onPressed` will be evaluated at runtime. So you either want to remove the `const` keyword from your custom button class constructor or you just pass the `onPressed` callback as it is to `super(onPressed:onPressed)` as I think the if statement you have right now is an unnecessary logic.

It also seems what you are doing is redundant. If you are looking to create a customized version of `TextButton`, it is better if you composite this as a new widget like so:

```dart
class CustomTextButton extends StatelessWidget {

  const CustomTextButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  //Add more fields as desired
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //Customize your button
    return TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: child);
  }
}
```